# Dynamic single file upload issue?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that generates multiple single file uploads. They currently upload fine but the upload file keeps overwriting $_SESSION['file'][0] in the array .

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['UploadCount'])){
    for($i=0;$i<=$_SESSION['UploadCount'];$i++){ ?>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <span class="control-label">Upload:</span>
        <div class="form-control file-input">    
            <label for="Attachment">
        <span class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="file" name="Attachment<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"id="Attachment" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
        Choose File
        </span>
        </label>
        <input class="file-name" type="text" readonly="readonly" placeholder="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['file'][$i])){ echo $_SESSION['file'][$i]; } else { echo "No file selected"; } ?>" />
        </div><br>
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['UploadError'][$i])){ ?><span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['UploadError'][$i]; ?></span><?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="Topic" class="control-label">Topic Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="Topic" cols="20" rows="3"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['Topic'])){ echo $_SESSION['Topic']; } ?></textarea>
    </div><?php } } ?>
```

The php to do upload is:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$_SESSION['UploadCount'];$i++){
    if(isset($_FILES["Attachment".$i]["name"])){
        if($_FILES["Attachment".$i]["name"])
        {  
            $uperror = "";

            include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Core/MultiUpload.php');

            if($uperror==""){               
                $_SESSION['file'][$i] = basename($_FILES["Attachment".$i]["name"]);  
                $_SESSION['stored'][$i] = $target_file;
            } else {
                $_SESSION['UploadError'][$i] = $uperror;
            }

            header( "Location: ".$hostname."/consultation/?page=".$Page."&assign=".$Assign ) ;
        exit; 
        }
    }
}
```

MultiUpload.php file is:

```
<?php
$uploadfoldercheck = "../Uploads/".$_SESSION['CompanyName']."/";
$uploadfoldercheck = str_replace(' ', '_', $uploadfoldercheck);
if (!file_exists($uploadfoldercheck)) 
{
    mkdir($uploadfoldercheck, 0755, true);

    $copy_index = $uploadfoldercheck."/index.php";

    copy('../Uploads/index.php', $copy_index);
} 

$filename = "../Uploads/".$_SESSION['CompanyName']."/".$_SESSION['UserID']."/";
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);

if (!file_exists($filename)) 
{
    mkdir($filename, 0755, true);

    $copy_index = $filename."/index.php";

    copy('../Uploads/index.php', $copy_index);
} 

$target_file = $filename . basename($_FILES["Attachment".$i]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uperror = "Sorry, file already exists:".$target_file;
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["Attachment"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    $uperror = "File to large. Max 2MB.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "pdf"  ) {
    $uperror = "Sorry, only PDF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($uploadOk=="1")
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Attachment".$i]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {

    } else {
        $uperror = "Unable to load File!";
    }
}

?>
```

Upload count gets initiliased:

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['UploadCount'])){
        $_SESSION['UploadCount']=3;
    }
```

Comment: Will you also add upload file code? @owen

Comment: I don't see where you set `UploadCount`

Comment: working now not sure what i changed to solve problem!